# Slim PHP Framework: can middleware be lazy-loaded?

Tags: php, lazy-loading, slim

While building a small Slim app, I noticed that all my middleware instances are getting created for every request. I have four routes in my app, only one of which requires a PDO instance, but all of which create an instance. Another route requires a SoapClient instance, but again, requests to any route result in instances being created. Can I do something differently to avoid that?

Here is a stripped down example showing what I mean:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

class Middleware {
    private $dep;
    public function __construct($dep = null) {
        $this->dep = $dep;
    }
    public function __invoke($req, $res) {
        $res->getBody()->write($this->dep ? 'Got dependency' : 'No dependency');
        return $res;
    }
}

$app = new \Slim\App();

$c = $app->getContainer();

$c['pdo'] = function ($c) {
    echo "PDO connection here<br/>\n";
    return (object) ['pdo' => true];
};

$c['middleware.nodep'] = function ($c) {
    return new Middleware();
};

$c['middleware.withdep'] = function ($c) {
    return new Middleware($c['pdo']);
};

$app->get('/nopdo', function () {})->add($c['middleware.nodep']);
$app->get('/withpdo', function () {})->add($c['middleware.withdep']);

$app->run();
```

Requests to /withpdo get the following response, as you would expect:

> PDO connection here
> Got dependency

Requests to /nopdo get this, which I don't want:

> PDO connection here
>  No dependency

So, is there a way to only instantiate the "PDO" instance for requests to /withpdo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the factory in `add()`, rather than just telling Slim about the DIC key.

i.e. change:

`->add($c['middleware.withdep']);`

to

`->add('middleware.withdep');`

This way, Slim will ask the DIC for 'middleware.withdep' when it needs it.

Comment: Ahhh, I did not pick up on that. Confirmed that it behaves as expected now. Thanks!